# Load a view by updating a table depending on the conditions inside controller - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this functions inside my controller

```
public function transact()
    {
        $merchantid = $this->input->post('merchantid');
        if(!$merchantid)
            {
                $row = array('error' => '<td align="center" width="50%" >204</td><td align="center" width="50%" >Empty merchant ID</td>');              
                $this->load->view('error_view',$row);
            }
        else
            {
                if(!$this->authentication->valid_mid($merchantid))
                    {
                        $row = array('error' => '<td align="center" width="50%" >403</td><td align="center" width="50%" >Authentication Failed</td>');
                        $this->load->view('error_view',$row);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $orderID = $this->input->post('orderID');
                            if(!$orderID)
                            {
                                $msg='Blank Order ID';
                                $this->displayerror($msg);
                            }
                        $amount = $this->input->post('amount');
                            if(!$amount)
                            {
                                $msg='Blank amount';
                                $this->displayerror($msg);
                            }
                        $email = $this->input->post('email');
                            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                            {
                                $msg='Invalid Email ID';
                                $this->displayerror($msg);
                            }
                        $mobileNo = $this->input->post('mobileNo');
                            if(!preg_match('/^\d{10}$/',$mobileNo))
                            {
                                $msg='Invalid mobile number';
                                $this->displayerror($msg);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    public function displayerror($msg)
    {
        $row = array('error' => '<td align="center" width="50%" >400</td><td align="center" width="50%" >'.$msg.'</td>');
        $this->load->view('error_view',$row);
    }
```

The error_view file is

```
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Response</h1>

    <div id="body" style="text-align:center">
        <p><b>Sorry , we are unable to process your request for the following reason/reasons</b></p>
        <div style="margin:50px auto">
            <table style="margin: 0 auto;">

                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="50%" ><b>Response Code</b></td>
                        <td align="center" width="50%" ><b>Reason</b></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <?php echo $error;?>
                    </tr>   


    </table>


        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Im getting the output as

[image]

The whole html is repeated for each function.But what I wanted is

[image]

Instead of repeating the whole html,I wanted to show the list of errors in the table.ie,if the orderID and amount is NULL,it should show both the error in the table as a row instead of repeatedly showing the whole html.Any posssibly way I can do it?Im new to codeigniter,finding it difficult to do things like this.Please help

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are loading view in each error message i.e. `$this->displayerror($msg);` if validation fails. And since multiple items are being validated so multiple if blocks are being executed each resulting in rending of HTML view.

A better approach would be to call display error message only after all the if blocks are executed and then looping through errors in view file.